# Passing a collection or array(2-D) from C# to multilevel collection in Oracle

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, oracle, plsql

Is it possible to pass list or multidimensional array from C# to an Oracle Procedure. 
If yes, then what is the method to create the oracle procedure.
I'm able to create a varray:

```
Create or Replace TYPE topic_tab IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(400);
```

Now I'm trying to create associative array of it using this [link](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=208):

```
CREATE TYPE tutorial_tab IS 
            TABLE OF topic_tab INDEX BY VARCHAR2(400);
```

But an error is coming: **use of pl/sql table is not allowed in this context**. PFA the image.

However, I'm unable to know the way of using this associative array as an input parameter in procedure. Due to which I won't be able to send any 2-D or List to the Procedure.

Please help me on the same. Is my approach is wrong?

[image]

Comment: I have no errors during creating your types (Oracle 11.1). Could you please attach your actions full listing?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in index-by-collection using. Here is just a reference form oracle doc:

> You **cannot declare** an associative array type at **schema level**.
>   Therefore, to pass an associative array variable as a parameter to a
>   standalone subprogram, you must declare the type of that variable in a
>   package specification. Doing so makes the type available to both the
>   invoked subprogram (which declares a formal parameter of that type)
>   and the invoking subprogram or anonymous block (which declares and
>   passes the variable of that type).

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#LNPLS99930

If you have no access to create packages in the database you can **try to look up** some existing appropriate collection type in oracle packages (in which you have access to). For example we have `DBMS_UTILITY`, `DBMS_SQL`. There are a lot of collection types in there whose you can to exploit. Let's look at `DBMS_UTILITY.ANYDATA_ARRAY`. You can pack your second dimension collections in this array.

```
DECLARE
     l_arr  DBMS_UTILITY.ANYDATA_ARRAY;
BEGIN
    l_arr(1) := anydata.ConvertCollection(topic_tab('topic1','topic2','topic3','topic4'));
END;
```

But `DBMS_UTILITY.ANYDATA_ARRAY` is `binary_integer` and it looks like you have to have varchar-index-by collection. Try to look up another one.

Comment: Is there any other approach available for completing this functionality. As my main purpose is to pass multidimensional array from C# to multi level collection stored procedure.

Comment: Have you read the quote? Here is a quote of the quote: *to pass an associative array variable as a parameter to a standalone subprogram, you must declare the type of that variable in a package specification* .

Comment: Hmm ok I understood it. But here we're not allowed to create package. We've to create only a procedure accepting an Array or cursor as a input parameter..

Comment: i've make some addition to the answer @Tans

Answer (score 0):

> Hey i have added the multidimensional array as per the requirment.
>   Hope this helps.

```
--Mutlidimensional array list pass to procedure

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE mul_obj IS OBJECT
(
FNAME VARCHAR2(100),
LNAME VARCHAR2(100)
);

--NESTED TABLE TYPE CREATION
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE MUL_TAB IS TABLE OF mul_obj;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_MLDIM(
    p_array_in IN MUL_TAB )
AS
BEGIN
  NULL;
  FOR I IN p_array_in.FIRST..p_array_in.LAST
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(p_array_in(i).fname||' '||p_array_in(i).lname);
  END LOOP;
END;

set serveroutput on;
exec TEST_MLDIM(MUL_TAB(mul_obj('Avrajit','Roy')));
```

> Hey i have tried to describe the cause of the concept you are tying to
>   implement. Hope this helps.

```
**--Since associative arrays can only be declared as PLSQL objects and not as SQL objects**
-- Anonymous block
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
TYPE topic_tab IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(400) index by VARCHAR2(10);
topic_tab_var topic_tab;
BEGIN
topic_tab_var('SON'):='Avrajit';
topic_tab_var('Father'):='Tapas';
topic_tab_var('Brother'):='Shubhojit';
dbms_output.put_line(topic_tab_var('SON'));
END;

**--By the way you can still do it without associative array

--Create normal nested table array SQL Object and us this as IN Param for procedure**

Create or Replace TYPE topic_tab IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(400);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_nested_array(
    p_array_in IN topic_tab )
AS
BEGIN
  NULL;
  --Your code logic should come here
END;
```

Comment: I think this is for single collection. Not the multi level collection. How to pass multidimensional array(jagged array) from C# to this procedure.

Comment: That too can be done by OBJECT types and then use nested table type. This will give you multidimensional array

Comment: As per your code. Do we've to pass varchar value for C# or directly a Array like this new Array[2]{new Array1,new Array2}

Comment: You have to take oracle object type from c# and map those with collection elements